# C# - How to send Insert with @Parameters to Database Connection Class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

Having a bit of an issue getting my insert to work properly. When I run the insert all within the same method, it works flawlessly... however when I try to send the Insert statement to my new Connection class (which I will have handle all database requests), I am getting the following error.

Note: I am using C# and Microsoft SQL Server.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@CollectionGroupID".
```

I believe I am not sending the parameters over, however I am not sure of the best way to do this.

Here's my AddGame method:

```
public static void AddGame(int gameId)
    {

        string statement = "INSERT INTO Collection (CollectionGroupID, SharedID, UserID, GameID, Owned, Favorited, WishList, DeletedIndicator, AddUser, AddDate, ModUser, ModDate) VALUES (@CollectionGroupID, @SharedID, @UserID, @GameID, @Owned, @Favorited, @WishList, @DeletedIndicator, @AddUser, @AddDate, @ModUser, @ModDate)";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CollectionGroupID", "0");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SharedID", "0");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", "0"); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID", gameId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owned", "Y");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Favorited", "N");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WishList", "N");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeletedIndicator", "N");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddUser", "test/admin");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddDate", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModUser", "test/admin");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModDate", DateTime.Now);


            Connection.Open();
            Connection.Statement(statement);
            Connection.Close();


        }
    }
```

And here is my Statement method in my Connection class

```
public static void Statement(string sql)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to submit data to the database...");

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

    }
```

I feel like perhaps I am overlooking a simple solution. Any help appreciated!

-Travis W.

Comment: It seems you're adding the parameters to a `SqlCommand` object that is not being used within the `Statement(string sql)` method.

Comment: You lose all your parameters since you only passed the string.  Get rid of that Statement method.  Just call the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery with the one you originally have.

Comment: I would suggest not using AddWithValue also. It can sometimes get datatypes wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command parameter is defined in `SqlCommand` in your `AddGame` method

you are passing the raw Sql over to the `Statement` method and inside the method you are creating another `SqlCommand` without parameter defined. This is why the parameters are not being passed in.

you should just do

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
//OR using (SqlConnection connection = Connection.Open())
//If you want to keep your Connection class to avoid having to pass in connection string.  
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, connection))
    {
        ...
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ()
    }
}
```

inside your `AddGame` method

Comment: Thanks - Looks like it's not really good practice to have a connection class. I'm going to remove it and go back to something like this.

Comment: While the intention of this answer is correct, given that the Connection class is custom and we don't have the code for that class in the question, it would be best if this were edited to use the SqlConnection class for future readers.  Or maybe I'm just being nit-picky, since there are probably a hundred questions like this on SO..

Comment: @EricH done. Gave OP another option to keep the connection class if he wants to .